# javascript conflict date/time with clickdesk

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, conflict

I have the following code for showing date/time stamp on my site:

```
<div id="clockbox" style="<font-size:9pt; padding:3px; text-align: center; text-transform: lowercase; overflow: hidden; height: 17px">
&nbsp;</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
tday  =new Array("Nedelja","Ponedeljak","Utorak","Sreda","Četvrtak","Petak","Subota");
tmonth=new Array("Januar","Februar","Mart","April","Maj","Jun","Jul","Avgust","Septembar","Oktobar","Novembar","Decembar");

function GetClock(){
d = new Date();
nday   = d.getDay();
nmonth = d.getMonth();
ndate  = d.getDate();
nyear = d.getYear();
nhour  = d.getHours();
nmin   = d.getMinutes();
nsec   = d.getSeconds();

if(nyear<1000) nyear=nyear+1900;

 if(nhour ==  0) {ap = " AM";nhour = 12;} 
else if(nhour <= 11) {ap = " AM";} 
else if(nhour == 12) {ap = " PM";} 
else if(nhour >= 13) {ap = " PM";nhour -= 12;}

if(nmin <= 9) {nmin = "0" +nmin;}
if(nsec <= 9) {nsec = "0" +nsec;}


document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML=""+tday[nday]+", "+ndate+". "+tmonth[nmonth]+" "+nyear+". "+nhour+":"+nmin+":"+nsec+ap+"";
setTimeout("GetClock()", 1000);
}
window.onload=GetClock;
</script>
```

It is showing nicely on all pages unless I have following lines on the same page:

```
<div class="clickdesk-widget">
<script type='text/javascript'>
var _glc =_glc || [];
_glc.push('<?php echo $widgetid; ?>');
var glcpath = (('https:' == document.location.protocol) ? 'https://contactuswidget.appspot.com/livily/browser/' : 'http://gae.clickdesk.com/livily/browser/');
var glcp = (('https:' == document.location.protocol) ? 'https://' : 'http://');
var glcspt = document.createElement('script'); glcspt.type = 'text/javascript'; glcspt.async = true;glcspt.src = glcpath + 'livechat.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(glcspt, s);
</script>
</div>
```

What is the problem there, can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring a global variables `d`, `nday`, etc. here:

```
d = new Date();
nday   = d.getDay();
nmonth = d.getMonth();
ndate  = d.getDate();
nyear = d.getYear();
nhour  = d.getHours();
nmin   = d.getMinutes();
nsec   = d.getSeconds();
```

try declare local variables instead (I guess that `d` variable is the root of your problenm because obfuscated code uses variable names like this) this way:

```
var d = new Date();
var nday   = d.getDay();
var nmonth = d.getMonth();
var ndate  = d.getDate();
var nyear = d.getYear();
var nhour  = d.getHours();
var nmin   = d.getMinutes();
var nsec   = d.getSeconds();
```

If it is online, send a link.

Comment: thank you for your reply. as the matter of fact, all is working just fine if I only comment out those lines from second script (it seems like they are not needed). anyway, I would like to accept your reply.